# Proper method of returning const char* from a function, e.g., overriding std::exception::what()

Tags: c++

When extending `std::exception`, I am wondering the proper way of overriding `what()`?

Lets say I have an exception class :

```
class MyException : public std::exception {
  public:
    MyException(const string& _type) : m_type(_type) {}

    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
      string s = "Error::" + _type;
      return s.c_str();
    }
}
```

I have used a static analysis tool on the above code, and it is complaining that the string `s` will leave the scope and destroy the memory associated with the string, so it could potentially be a problem if I use `what()` in some part of my code.

If there a proper way of returning a `const char*` from a function without these issues retaining proper memory management?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to store the `string` instance inside your class, otherwise the memory for it will be freed when your `what()` function returns, leaving the caller with a dangling pointer:

```
class MyException : public std::exception {
  public:
    MyException(const std::string& _type)
      : m_what("Error::" + _type)
    {
    }

    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
      return m_what.c_str();
    }

  private:
    std::string m_what;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are returning a pointer to a temporary that will be destroyed when the `what()` call exits.

Derive your exception class from [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) instead of `std::exception`. Then change the code to:

```
class MyException : public std::runtime_error {
  public:
    MyException(const string& _type) 
    : std::runtime_error("Error::" + _type) 
    {}
};
```

`std::runtime_error` implements the `what()` member function, so there's no need for your class to implement it.